# Singleton instance is always null

Tags: c#, singleton

I have an ASP.net with MVC program with the current singleton class:

```
    public sealed class Foo
{
    private static volatile Foo_instance;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();
    private List<Obj> _objList;

    private Foo()
    {
        _objList = new List<Obj>();
    }

    public static Foo Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    _instance = new Foo();
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
    public void AddObjToList(Obj _object)
    {
        lock (_instance)
        {
            _objList.Add(_object);
        }
    }   
    public void FindAndRemoveObj(string id) 
    {
        lock (_instance)
        {
            Obj _object = null;
            _object= _objList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.UniKey == id);
            if (_object!= null) 
            {
                _objList.Remove(object);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first time that a class get the instance of this class it will return a new/clean instace of foo class, as expected, and then populating the list however a second class that will remove itens from the same list is receveing an new instance with an empty list.

Comment: Firstly, you should double-check that your _instance is null. To do this you should check if _instance is null again after you lock(syncRoot). Otherwise several threads may end up new'ing _instance.  
Secondly, I would advice against implementing Singletons this way in an MVC application. Do you know exactly what the life-time of a static is when hosted in a webserver??. Use a proper IOC framework to manage liftetime instead.

Comment: Looks like i was ninja'ed by Phil. He basically writes the same as me: Double-lock, and don't use statics in an IIS.

Comment: Ok, so my knowledge about double-check was mistaken. Thanks for the explanation. I'm currently using UnityFramework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conclusion was that the asp.net is creating new instances of the domain and that causes a new singleton object each time. I have searched how to sync objects between domains but that is too "workaround" for me, so I decided to add a boolean column that update the value with the confirmation or failure.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

This code has the lock in the wrong place:

```
if (_instance == null)
{
    lock (syncRoot)
    {
        _instance = new Foo();
    }
}
```

As thread 1 creates _instance, a second thread will block on the lock, then create  _instance anew when it is released.

Another thing to be careful about it that you should never rely on static variables in IIS across server lookups.  The application pool can be recycled at any time.

Comment: I removed the lock but the instance still null for the second thread. 
Is there a way to control the IIS recycling?

Comment: Application pool recycling is configurable in IIS, but that isn't a robust solution to your problem.  Why are you storing this information - does it need to be persisted?  Or just shared between threads during the normal operation of the web site?

Comment: I´m sending messages.  I'm storing the message id in memory, waiting for the confirmation that a task was completed by the receiver.

Comment: I've done something similar in a subscriber / publisher scenario.  I used a static to store a collection of subscribers in a very similar way, so it can be effective.  To understand the problem, I'd recommend adding diagnostic logging into the application to output process ID and application domain ID:

`var applicationDomainID = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Id;`
`var processID = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;`

If process and appdomain are the same for both threads, then it's further head scratching time.

Comment: The applicationDomainID is different but the processID is the same

Comment: The process is the Application Pool process.  The AppDomain is different either because it has been recycled (unlikely, but it can be triggered by Visual Studio if you're debugging) or ...  Are subscriber / publisher calling into the web application in the same way?  Or is one using Web API and the other accessing a web page?

Comment: I did a little test and Web API and web pages both use the same AppDomain, so it's not that